# Check if excel value is available in another column

Tags: excel

I went through some posts but couldn't find much help.

I have a data set like this

```
Column A   Column B   Column C 
ABC        ZZZ        123
BBB        ABC        234
ZZZ        BBB        567
```

I need to write a formula in Column D that if ABC is available in Column B, get me Column C value.

I tried all VLOOKUP functions but couldn't find one appropriately. Can someone please help on the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this with VLOOKUP in D1

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,$B$1:$C$3,2,0)
```

After writing this in D1, drag this to the end
[image]

Comment: can u pls explain a little bit on what 2,0 means in the formula? I m getting #REF! as the output.

Comment: Its working for me, 2 means getting the value from second column in array B1 to C3 and 0 is used for exact match with A1. I have added an image also in my answer for more clarification

Answer (score 0):

Column A    Column B    Column C     Column D
ABC         ZZZ         123           =VLOOKUP(L2,$M$2:$N$4,2,0)
BBB         ABC         234           567
ZZZ         BBB         567           123